# Data vectorization (get_dummies 3 columns to matrix)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector, scipy

I have a task, which must be optimally solved. I have 50 categories and 10,000 stores that can have products from these categories, but all this in 3 columns

```
id_store  category    qnty
    1         1        50
    1         2        32
    1         15       44
    2         1        333
    2         4        33
    2         5        15
    2         15       12
    2         35       14
    3         3        14
    ....
```

It is necessary to make a matrix out of this, where row - id_store, and columns - category, and their intersection - qnty:

```
id_shop/category  1   2   3   4 ...15  16... 35   36
   1              50  32  0   0    44  0     0    0
   2              333 0   0   33   12  0     14   0
   3              0   0   14  0    0   0     0    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pandas`, which is a library specifically designed for dataframes like yours. From the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), I found this example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
...                            'two'],
...                    'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
...                    'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
...                    'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})
```

-

```
>>> df
    foo   bar  baz  zoo
0   one   A    1    x
1   one   B    2    y
2   one   C    3    z
3   two   A    4    q
4   two   B    5    w
5   two   C    6    t
```

-

```
>>> df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
bar  A   B   C
foo
one  1   2   3
two  4   5   6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy sparse matrices to do this. Documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html).

```
D = sp.sparse.coo_matrix((qnty,(id_store,category))) # creates a sparse matrix from numpy vectors (np.ndarray)
```

If you want to make it a dense `np.ndarray`, just use:

```
D = D.toarray()
```

Or if you prefer the numpy `np.matrix` type, just use:

```
D = D.todense()
```